# Methods of Treatment Effect Heterogeneity Estimation (Observation Data)

Tags: regression, econometrics, causality, propensity-scores

Given observational data, where a 
"treatment" is chosen by the unit of observation or not, are there any standard methods of ascertaining not just if the treatment has effect overall (ATT), but construct estimates of the treatment effect for various covariate patterns?

For example, one idea is to use matching (1:1) with propensity scores to produce a set of treated and control records. Then use that dataset to build a predictive model, using the interaction of the variables used to match with the treated indicator. Then the treated group is ran through the model with treatment =1 and again with treatment =0 and the estimates subtracted.